# Making routing link non clickable

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I have the following html

```
<!--SIDE NAV-->
<div class="container-fluid" id="container-fluid">
<div class="row content">
<div class="col-sm-3 sidenav">
  <h4>Returns Panel</h4>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
    <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
      <a routerLink="/">Enter Order ID</a></li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/Pid">Select PID</a></li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/Reasons">Select Reasons for Return</a></li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a >Upload Images</a></li>
  </ul><br>
</div>
```

I want that the user cannot click on these links but these links should be visible. The user should not be able to change the flow of the form. 
How can I do that? I need the routing to be operational as I route to display different forms.

Comment: Do you want to disable all of them or a single one?

Comment: All of them. But disable them only for user click, not for routing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html

```
<a [routerLink]="isActive ? '/link' : null">label</a>
```

Component

```
isActive: boolean = true
```

Comment: This works but it also removes the active class css.

Answer (score 0):

> Use *ngIf

```html
<a *ngIf="isEnabled" [routerlink]="/some_state_url">Link</a>
<span *ngIf="!isEnabled" [ngClass]="{'class-disabled':!isEnabled}">Link</span>
```